# Is it true that $x(1-x)=y(1-y)$ if and only if $x=y$?

Tags: functions, polynomials

Consider two numbers $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $0\leq y\leq 1$. Is it true that $x(1-x)=y(1-y)$ if and only if $x=y$? If not, can you give a counterexample?

Comment: $x=0$, $y=1{}$.

Comment: ok, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Each side of the equation has two solutions; $x= 0, 1$ and $y = 0, 1$. It's perfectly reasonable for the solutions to either coincide or be different.

Comment: The function $f\colon x\mapsto x(1-x)$ is symmetric around $1/2$. So for any $t\in[0,1/2]$, $f(1/2-t)=f(1/2+t)$.

Comment: @STF No, see my answer

Comment: if.  But not only if.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true. Any pair of numbers such that $x+y=1$ will work as an example (except when both are $1/2$). This is because $x=1-y$ and $y=1-x$.

This is in fact the only way to make this happen.

Answer (score 3):

$$x(1-x) = y(1-y) \implies -x^2+x-y(1-y)=0 \implies x^2-x+y(1-y)=0\text{.}$$
By the quadratic formula,
$$x = \dfrac{1\pm \sqrt{1-4(1)y(1-y)}}{2}=\dfrac{1 \pm \sqrt{1-4y(1-y)}}{2} = \dfrac{1\pm \sqrt{1-4y+4y^2}}{2} = \dfrac{1 \pm |2y-1|}{2}\text{,}$$
so any pair $\left(\dfrac{1 + |2y-1|}{2}, y\right)$ or $\left(\dfrac{1 - |2y-1|}{2}, y\right)$ for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ will work. Obviously, $x = y$ isn't necessary.

Comment: This turns out to return the same numbers as my answer in the range specified.

Answer (score 2):

Since $x(1-x)-y(1-y)$ can be factored as $(x-y)[1-(x+y)]$, the equation $x(1-x)=y(1-y)$ holds if and only if $x=y$ or $x+y=1$.